# fetching all product images in commerce.js

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce, commerce.js

**Hi!**
I'm building an e-commerce using React + Commerce.js.

I'm facing this issue: when I fetch *(using `commerce.products.list()`)* the product object with all its specs (name, price, description, image, etc...), all the image properties are related to the **main image.**
However, on commerce.js you can upload **several images per product**, and I want to fetch all these images to create a Product Details page where you can browse through the different images.

Do you know how to do this?

Note: I read something about creating 'assets' and uploading images from the CLI, but if commerce.js allows you to create your store and several images per product, isn't there a way to access these already uploaded images through the API instead of having to re-upload as assets?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have already uploaded your images for your product, you can retrieve a collection of uploaded assets by using `product.assets` :)